# How to extract data with sql from multiple sqlite3 databases using R

Tags: sql, r, sqlite

I would like to extract data using an sql script in R to extract data from a lot (about 75) of sqlite3 databases. How would I go about in R to achieve that?

Can anyone recommend a strategy using R?

Comment: Perhaps start [extracting data from one SQLLite DB](https://gist.github.com/jwolfson/72bc7d7fd8d339955b38), and when this works for one, use `lapply` or `map` to go over a whole list.

Comment: Have you researched available libraries' docs to help you with that?